# How to customize PHP import script

Tags: php, html

I'm attempting to import specific external content into designated sections of my custom website template.

My WP theme came with a import.php file for a website that I don't need to import content from.

I would like to duplicate the capability to import external content from the files that came with the theme, but I want to customize where content is imported from (other external sources) and load it to the custom template.

I thought this would be an easier task than creating a new script.

However, creating a new script may be much simpler... I don't know what I'm doing.

I've researched ways that I can import external content outside of utilizing the files that came with my theme:

- Using ImportXML via GoogleSheets and importing... but I haven't discovered a way to import specific XML data to designated sections of my custom template.

I believe the above mentioned method would work. However, I am lost with the coding language and it is contributing to my not discovering a solution... I think.

Currently, I have secluded the specific template file that I want to use and have stripped the preloaded/imported content from it, then I replaced it with the content from the external source manually using the brackets app, I then created a folder in cPanel and uploaded the manually edited template which works as I want... but this takes up too much time.

Any pointers on how to automate the above task?

I'm assuming I can create a custom PHP import file but I am completely new to this type of programming.

Other options I've discovered:

- Using a .txt and JS in div (this breaks the custom template)
- Using API somehow...

In newbie terms:

I want to get content from external site HTML tags ---> and place that content in designated HTML tags (with no content) in my custom template ---> in order to fill in the tags with no content with content scraped from the external site.

Best way I can explain it.

Please assist.

Comment: Using an API is your best bet, if an API is available for the site you are referring to. Scraping is, a lot of the time, against the site's terms of use. You may want to hire someone capable of implementing it or at the very least evaluating it.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: ImportXML with google sheets is working. I suppose I can upload data to Woocommerce product page. However, I would like to use a specific product page template to upload the data to and I have not found a way to do this nor have I found product page templates elsewhere which would make things much easier as I would be avoiding any trivial work. This seems to be more of a dream though...